# How to search the property of a Navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, where-clause, navigation-properties

I'm creating a database using ASP.NET which features two classes, `Countries` and `Species`. The Species model contains an `ICollection` of type `Country`, and I am trying to allow for a search string on the Species Index view to check not only for names of Species, but if the user types the name of a Country instead, to return Species who's Country Collections include a Country with a Name that matches the search string:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string Poison, string Venom)
{
    var species = db.Species.Include(s => s.Countries);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))        
    {   
        species = species.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString) || **s has a country who's Name contains searchString**);    
    }
}
```

This is my first question on stackoverflow, I'm not sure how many examples of my failed attempts are required, but the error messages I have received are largely based on being unable to convert type Country to String:

> Values of type 'collection[NSDBz.DAL.Country(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]' can not be converted to string.

I can see there are similar questions being asked but their requirements are a bit more intricate so I'm unable, at my present skill level, to apply the solutions there to my problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your error, it appears you are trying to compare the `Countries` collection to the string, rather than checking if any of the countries *in the collection* have a matching name.  I would suggest trying something similar to the following:

```
s.Countries.Any(c => c.Name.Contains(searchString))
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you need species which has searchString counties, so following Linq will return you a list of species which has your search string countries

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string Poison, string Venom)
{
    var species = db.Species.Include(s => s.Countries);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))        
    {   
        species = species.Where(s => s.Countries.Any(c => c.Name.Contains(searchString)));    
    }
}
```